# Travis-Ci: Check if build is off push or pull request

Tags: bash, travis-ci

I want to run a section of the script only when the build is off a push and not a PR. But on build it doesn't go. How can I only run the section when the build is off a push?

```
if [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ]; then
setup_git
commit_website_files
publish_gh_pages
fi
```

Comment: Use `!=` instead, see [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Convenience-Variables).

Comment: @набиячлэвэлиь tried that didn't work still. Just did `if [ "${secure:-false}" != "false" ]; then` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use secure environment variables to determine if PR or push. Secure environment variables aren't available in push

```
if [ "${ghToken:-false}" != "false" ]; then
setup_git
commit_website_files
publish_gh_pages
fi
```